# definition of caffe.Layer class

Tags: neural-network, caffe, pycaffe

When defining a python layer in Caffe like [this](https://github.com/snapfinger/fcn.berkeleyvision.org/blob/master/voc_layers.py), there are fields like `voc_dir`, `split`,`random`, etc, some of them are said to inherit from `caffe.Layer` class.

However where can I find the definition of `caffe.Layer` class? Searched through Caffe's documentation but they provide very little explanation, and didn't find it after looking in several directories in their code base.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Layer class is implemented in the (core) C++ code of caffe. ([link](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/include/caffe/layer.hpp))
The Boost Python wrapper defines the interface as follows, in [python/_caffe.cpp](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/python/caffe/_caffe.cpp) (which is compiled to python/caffe/_caffe.so):

```
bp::class_<Layer<Dtype>, shared_ptr<PythonLayer<Dtype> >,
boost::noncopyable>("Layer", bp::init<const LayerParameter&>())
```

This interface is then imported by the [caffe module init](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/python/caffe/__init__.py):

```
from ._caffe import init_log, log, set_mode_cpu, set_mode_gpu, set_device, **Layer**
```

Comment: you can do `dir(caffe.Layer)` in python to see what are the basic methods/properties exposed through the interface.

Comment: In addition to `dir(caffe.Layer)`, `help(caffe.Layer)` produces more readable documentation.